Deleting files if duplicated names isn't epub or kepub
So I downloaded tons of ebooks from telegram, and now I have tons of files im different formats as well.
So I would like to remove the duplicates (if any) and keep only the 'epub' or 'kepub' format from that ebook 'copy'.
That part I figure it out, but when it's not a 'copy' I want to keep the file 'pdf' or whatever format.
import os

diretorio = '/home/jcsantos/Desktop/teste_ebook'


def apagar_ficheiros(diretorio):
    ficheiros_por_nome = {}

    for ficheiro in os.listdir(diretorio):
        nome, ext = os.path.splitext(ficheiro)
        if ext not in ['.epub', '.kepub']:
            if nome not in ficheiros_por_nome:
                ficheiros_por_nome[nome] = []            
            ficheiros_por_nome[nome].append(ficheiro)
    
    for ficheiros in ficheiros_por_nome.values():
        for ficheiro in ficheiros:
            caminho = os.path.join(diretorio, ficheiro)
            print(f'Apagando: {caminho}')
            os.remove(caminho)


apagar_ficheiros(diretorio)

The list:
(20240824-PT) Fugas Público.pdf
1_384198847695421742.pdf
01. FOURTH WING by Rebecca Yarros.epub
01. Gone - O Mundo Termina Aqui - Michael Grant.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.mobi
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.pdf
1. As Mentiras de Locke – Scott Lynch.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.mobi
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.pdf
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.azw3
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.epub
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.mobi
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.pdf
1. Tess Gerritsen (Rizzoli & Isles) - O Cirurgiao.epub

What I want to keep after program delete the duplicated:
(20240824-PT) Fugas Público.pdf
1_384198847695421742.pdf
01. FOURTH WING by Rebecca Yarros.epub
01. Gone - O Mundo Termina Aqui - Michael Grant.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.epub
1. As Mentiras de Locke – Scott Lynch.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.epub
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.epub
1. Tess Gerritsen (Rizzoli & Isles) - O Cirurgiao.epub


I expect that keeps the files that don't have any copy

You could at first create a dict where the keys represent the filenames and the values are a list of existing file extensions:
from pathlib import Path

files = {}

for x in Path(".").iterdir():
    if x.is_file():
        files.setdefault(x.stem, []).append(x.suffix)
print(files)

Output:
{'1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon': ['.pdf',
  '.epub',
  '.mobi'],
 '01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani': ['.epub', '.mobi', '.pdf'],
 '1. Tess Gerritsen (Rizzoli & Isles) - O Cirurgiao': ['.epub'],
 '1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas': ['.pdf', '.azw3', '.epub', '.mobi'],
 '(20240824-PT) Fugas Público': ['.pdf'],
 '1_384198847695421742': ['.pdf'],
 '1. As Mentiras de Locke – Scott Lynch': ['.epub'],
 '01. FOURTH WING by Rebecca Yarros': ['.epub'],
 '01. Gone - O Mundo Termina Aqui - Michael Grant': ['.epub']}

After that you loop through that list and delete all filenames that exist several times and use a custom sort to keep the file extension you prefer:
def custom_sort(suffix):
    priorities = {'.epub':1, '.kepub':2, '.pdf':3}
    return priorities.get(suffix, 4)   

for n,s in files.items():
    for x in sorted(s, key=custom_sort)[1:]:
        Path(n+x).unlink()


There are many ways to do it, I'd do this way:

Group the filelist into a dictionary. Keys are filenames and values are list of extensions for that filename
Iterate items of that dictionary and sort the list of extension the way that epub/kepub are on the last position.
Print/store/... the filname + extension on the last position.

files = """\
(20240824-PT) Fugas Público.pdf
1_384198847695421742.pdf
01. FOURTH WING by Rebecca Yarros.epub
01. Gone - O Mundo Termina Aqui - Michael Grant.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.mobi
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.pdf
1. As Mentiras de Locke – Scott Lynch.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.mobi
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.pdf
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.azw3
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.epub
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.mobi
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.pdf
1. Tess Gerritsen (Rizzoli & Isles) - O Cirurgiao.epub""".splitlines()

tmp = {}
for f in files:
    filename, extension = f.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    tmp.setdefault(filename, []).append(extension)

for k, v in tmp.items():
    v.sort(key=lambda extension: extension in {"epub", "kepub"})
    print(f"{k}.{v[-1]}")

Prints:
(20240824-PT) Fugas Público.pdf
1_384198847695421742.pdf
01. FOURTH WING by Rebecca Yarros.epub
01. Gone - O Mundo Termina Aqui - Michael Grant.epub
01.A Escola do Bem e do Mal - Soman Chainani.epub
1. As Mentiras de Locke – Scott Lynch.epub
1. Eu sei o que você está pensando – John Verdon.epub
1. O Amante - Jodi Ellen Malpas.epub
1. Tess Gerritsen (Rizzoli & Isles) - O Cirurgiao.epub

